# Replicate existing LVM (xfs Filesystems) over network

Tags: replication, lvm, xfs

i need to replicate 2 Productive Servers on a Backup Server (something like High Availability)

Facts:

3 Servers: 2 Productive (1 Prod_serv: VG has 30TB and 5 LVM's; 2 Prod_Serv - VG has 10TB and 3 LVM; Backup_Serv - 70 TB but no VGs yet. Only OS installed )

the 2 Productive Servers are running Centos 6. Backup_Serv is running Centos 7

All 3 Servers are configured with LVM.

Filesystem: XFS

All Servers are connected with 10G network interfaces.

Q1: What would be the best way to replicate the 2 Productive Servers on the Backup Server?

Q2: Is there any way i could install and configure DRBD on the existing LVM's without having to wipe the data?

Looking forward for your answers!